# Blob-изображение из JS в Python

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование, python-3.x, flask

На веб-странице есть обработчик события написанный на JavaScript, который позволяет по нажатию Ctrl+V загрузить из буфера обмена изображение в браузер в виде blob и просто отобразить на странице у самого пользователя, не отправляя его куда-то на сервер.

Имеется Python скрипт (Flask?), которому нужно передать этот blob с изображением для дальнейших вычислений. Все происходит на клиентской стороне.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: а какие наработки есть уже? или все с нуля нужно сделать?

Comment: Отправить `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich Наработки есть, но здесь я прошу подказать способ, которым можно это сделать, а не писать за меня код. :)

Comment: @Other Каким образом это лучше всего сделать? Можно подробнее?

Comment: Ну покажите что у Вас уже сделано, мы увидим что Вы действительно хотите помощи, а не сделать за Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправляйте через Ajax-запросом через `FormData`, а на сервере обрабатывайте, как загрузку обычного файла. На клиенте можно, например, так:

```
element.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
    var items = event.clipboardData.items;
    var formData = new FormData;
    for (let item of items) {
        if (item.type.indexOf('image') != -1) {
            formData.append('file[]', item.getAsFile());
        }
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('POST', url, true);

    request.onload = function() {
        // 
    };

    request.send(formData);
});
```